# Optaplanner: alternatives to annotating

Tags: java, annotations, optaplanner

What alternatives are there to annotating classes with `PlanningVariable` and `PlanningEntity`? I do not have access to modify these classes. Is it possible to do it in code or in a properties file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this unresolved community jira issue: [PLANNER-151](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-151) (no customer request yet though)

A future version of OptaPlanner will support declaring annotations in an xml file, according to the same system that allows to declare JPA annotations in an `orm.xml` file to avoid cluttering your domain with our annotations.